How to Block Outgoing Emails with Forged "From" Headers?
I'm managing a mail server stack using Postfix, Dovecot, SpamAssassin, and Amavis. My primary concern is outgoing emails where authenticated users attempt to set a From address different from their actual identity, specifically targeting internal and external users with forged sender addresses like admin@mydomain.com.
While I'm aware that there are legitimate scenarios for differing envelope and From headers (e.g., for mailing lists or system-generated notifications), there are no valid use cases in our environment where regular users should be sending such emails. By policy, we only allow the server itself to use different envelope and header addresses for specific system functions—not users via mail clients or custom scripts.
I’m currently using reject_sender_login_mismatch in Postfix, which restricts the envelope sender based on user login maps, but it doesn’t enforce a match between the envelope and From header in the message body.
What’s the best way to configure Postfix, Amavis, or another tool in this stack to prevent authenticated users from sending outgoing emails with mismatched or forged From headers?

This question is similar to: How to limit the From header to match MAIL FROM in postfix?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
